# svn: REPORT response handling failed to complete the editor drive

Tags: svn

I created a branch in svn and I'm trying to merge it back into the trunk. I am running the command:

```
# In the branch working copy
svn log --stop-on-copy

# In the trunk working copy
svn merge -r <last revision from previous command>:HEAD <path to branch>
```

And I receive the response:

```
svn: REPORT response handling failed to complete the editor drive
```

I don't understand the error message at all. It doesn't seem to be a server issue as I can still run 'svn update' and I can merge from the trunk into the branch, but I can't merge from the branch into the trunk. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. It was because I had updated the branch with changes from the trunk. So when I tried to merge from when the branch was created to the current trunk, svn ended up having a heart attack and couldn't figure out what to do during the revisions where a merge occurred. I was able to fix it by leaving out those specific revisions while merging back to the trunk.